# How can I create or open a libsodium compatible sealed box in pure Java

Tags: java, encryption, public-key-encryption, elliptic-curve, libsodium

libsodium provides an API to create or open a sealed box documented here https://download.libsodium.org/doc/public-key_cryptography/sealed_boxes.html

How can I achieve the same in pure Java, so that allows me to open a box created by libsodium or create one that libsodium can open?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following example code can create and open a libsodium sealed box.

It requires TweetNaclFast from https://github.com/InstantWebP2P/tweetnacl-java and a Blake2b hash implementation, for example the one from https://github.com/alphazero/Blake2b

```
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import ove.crypto.digest.Blake2b;
import com.iwebpp.crypto.TweetNaclFast;


/**
 * Example how to open sealed boxes in pure java (libsodium sealed boxes according to 
 * https://download.libsodium.org/doc/public-key_cryptography/sealed_boxes.html)
 * 
 * Has a dependency on TweetNaclFast and Blake2B, for example
 * 
 * https://github.com/alphazero/Blake2b
 * and
 * https://github.com/InstantWebP2P/tweetnacl-java
 * 
 */
public class SealedBoxUtility {


public static final int crypto_box_NONCEBYTES = 24;
public static final int crypto_box_PUBLICKEYBYTES = 32;
public static final int crypto_box_MACBYTES = 16;
public static final int crypto_box_SEALBYTES = (crypto_box_PUBLICKEYBYTES + crypto_box_MACBYTES);

//  libsodium
//  int crypto_box_seal(unsigned char *c, const unsigned char *m,
//            unsigned long long mlen, const unsigned char *pk);


/**
 * Encrypt in  a sealed box
 *
 * @param clearText clear text
 * @param receiverPubKey receiver public key
 * @return encrypted message
 * @throws GeneralSecurityException 
 */
public static byte[] crypto_box_seal(byte[] clearText, byte[] receiverPubKey) throws GeneralSecurityException {

    // create ephemeral keypair for sender
    TweetNaclFast.Box.KeyPair ephkeypair = TweetNaclFast.Box.keyPair();
    // create nonce
    byte[] nonce = crypto_box_seal_nonce(ephkeypair.getPublicKey(), receiverPubKey);
    TweetNaclFast.Box box = new TweetNaclFast.Box(receiverPubKey, ephkeypair.getSecretKey());
    byte[] ciphertext = box.box(clearText, nonce);
    if (ciphertext == null) throw new GeneralSecurityException("could not create box");

    byte[] sealedbox = new byte[ciphertext.length + crypto_box_PUBLICKEYBYTES];
    byte[] ephpubkey = ephkeypair.getPublicKey();
    for (int i = 0; i < crypto_box_PUBLICKEYBYTES; i ++)
        sealedbox[i] = ephpubkey[i];

    for(int i = 0; i < ciphertext.length; i ++)
        sealedbox[i+crypto_box_PUBLICKEYBYTES]=ciphertext[i];

    return sealedbox;
}

//  libsodium:
//      int
//      crypto_box_seal_open(unsigned char *m, const unsigned char *c,
//                           unsigned long long clen,
//                           const unsigned char *pk, const unsigned char *sk)

/**
 * Decrypt a sealed box
 *
 * @param c ciphertext
 * @param pk receiver public key
 * @param sk receiver secret key
 * @return decrypted message
 * @throws GeneralSecurityException 
 */
public static byte[] crypto_box_seal_open( byte[]c, byte[] pk, byte[]sk ) throws GeneralSecurityException{
    if ( c.length < crypto_box_SEALBYTES) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Ciphertext too short");

    byte[] pksender = Arrays.copyOfRange(c, 0, crypto_box_PUBLICKEYBYTES);
    byte[] ciphertextwithmac = Arrays.copyOfRange(c, crypto_box_PUBLICKEYBYTES , c.length);
    byte[] nonce = crypto_box_seal_nonce(pksender,pk);

    TweetNaclFast.Box box = new TweetNaclFast.Box(pksender, sk);
    byte[] cleartext = box.open(ciphertextwithmac, nonce);
    if (cleartext == null) throw new GeneralSecurityException("could not open box");
    return cleartext;
}


/**
 *  hash the combination of senderpk + mypk into nonce using blake2b hash
 * @param senderpk the senders public key
 * @param mypk my own public key
 * @return the nonce computed using Blake2b generic hash
 */
public static byte[] crypto_box_seal_nonce(byte[] senderpk, byte[] mypk){
// C source ported from libsodium
//      crypto_generichash_state st;
//
//      crypto_generichash_init(&st, NULL, 0U, crypto_box_NONCEBYTES);
//      crypto_generichash_update(&st, pk1, crypto_box_PUBLICKEYBYTES);
//      crypto_generichash_update(&st, pk2, crypto_box_PUBLICKEYBYTES);
//      crypto_generichash_final(&st, nonce, crypto_box_NONCEBYTES);
//
//      return 0;
    final Blake2b blake2b = Blake2b.Digest.newInstance( crypto_box_NONCEBYTES ); 
    blake2b.update(senderpk);
    blake2b.update(mypk);
    byte[] nonce = blake2b.digest();
    if (nonce == null || nonce.length!=crypto_box_NONCEBYTES) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Blake2b hashing failed");
    return nonce;


}

}
```